# WebPack 4 SplitChunksPlugin for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm producing bundles for a NodeJS 8.x (AWS Lambda) and would like to selectively minify chunks (business code to remain non-minified and third party libraries to be minified to save on bundle size).

I've configured Webpack as below but it main bundle of mine doesn't work because it is not built to be able to require the other files (one file for each npm dependency). 
How can I configure WebPack to produce chunks which can require each other in NodeJS?

```js
splitChunks: {
    chunks: 'all',
    maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
    minSize: 0,
    cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            name: (module) => {
                const packageName = module.context.match(/[\\/]node_modules[\\/](.*?)([\\/]|$)/)[1];
                return `npm.${packageName}`;
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Avij see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of minifying the output chunks selectively, I opted to not use the SplitChunksPlugin at all and instead minify in a custom loader as part of the compilation.

This makes it possible to cherry pick exactly which input files (Webpack calls them assets) you want to minify and which ones you don't.

```sh
npm install terser --save-dev
```

**tools/es-minify-loader.js**

```
const Terser = require('terser');

module.exports = function esMinifyLoader(source) {
    const output = Terser.minify(source, { compress: true, mangle: true });
    return output.code;
};
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
...
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            exclude: [
                /dont-minify-this-file\.js/,
                /some-library-or-folder-you-dont-want-minified/i,
            ],
            test: [
                /\.js$/
            ],
            use: [
                {
                    loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'tools/es-minify-loader.js'),
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
...
```